# get all tags with sql query

Tags: php, sql

I have this sql that is made by help of others.

```
$sql ="
select e.*, i.*, group_concat( t.tag separator ',') as tag_list
from nv_entries e
JOIN nv_tags t on t.entrie_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN nv_images i on i.entrie_id = e.id

where t.tag in ( $tag_list )
group  by e.id
having count(t.id) = $num_tags ";
```

The result is this (i only show one entrie here, could be more):

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [band] => Kids for Cash
            [album] => No More Walls E.P.
            [label] => 
            [year] => 1986
            [text] => Text about album kids for cash.
            [entrie_id] => 2
            [source] => img02_9lch1.png
            [tag_list] => tree
        )
```

For the tags, i have to show all tags that a entrie has and highlight the tags that where used to get the result. In this case `[tag_list] => tree` only shows one tag, the one that was used in the search field. My question is, how can i get a result like this?:

```
            ...
            [tag_list] => tree, green, foo, bar
            [used_tags] => tree
        )
```

As a array is also good, but then please also an array when it's just one item.

Comment: The query you have already does it. But due to the `HAVING` clause, you are limiting the results to only those which have a specific number of tags (`$num_tags`). Try removing the `HAVING` clause and see if it works as you want.

Comment: More clear now.I think your're trying 2 mutual excluding things: 1. getting all results with exactly ALL the tag you search (having count()...) 2. getting all result with at least your search tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly use >= in the having condition

```
$sql ="
select e.*, i.*, group_concat( t.tag separator ',') as tag_list
from nv_entries e
LEFT JOIN nv_images i on i.entrie_id = e.id
JOIN nv_tags t on t.entrie_id = e.id

where t.tag in ( $tag_list )
group  by e.id
having count(t.id) >= $num_tags ";
```

ADD

subquery approach:

```
$sql ="
select e.*, i.*, group_concat( t.tag separator ',') as tag_list
from nv_entries e
JOIN nv_tags t on t.entrie_id in (
select se.id 
from nv_entries se
JOIN nv_tags st on st.entrie_id = se.id

where st.tag in ( $tag_list )

group  by se.id
having count(st.id) >= $num_tags

)
    LEFT JOIN nv_images i on i.entrie_id = e.id
    WHERE 1
    group by e.id
 ";
```

Into subquery I get the ID list of entrie havin at least requested tags, then in main query I get all infox

ADD fixed query (see asker comment)

subquery approach, fix the lost join between "e" and "t" :

```
$sql ="
select e.*, i.*, group_concat( t.tag separator ',') as tag_list
from nv_entries e
JOIN nv_tags t on t.entrie_id = e.id 
    LEFT JOIN nv_images i on i.entrie_id = e.id
    WHERE e.id in  (
select se.id 
from nv_entries se
JOIN nv_tags st on st.entrie_id = se.id

where st.tag in ( $tag_list )

group  by se.id
having count(st.id) >= $num_tags

)
    group by e.id
 ";
```

Comment: well, this shows the used tags but not all tags.
So it's part correct. `[tag_list] => green,tree` shows the 2 tags i typed in the search query, however apart from that i also need to have the other tags from the entrie. I hope i make myself clear.

Comment: hope you don't get sick of me, your update returns tags from combined entries for example: `  [tag_list] => rousseau,green,woodsy,band photo,12IN,tree,civilization,Atco,1960's,Fuzz,rousseau,woodsy,band photo,12IN,tree,civilization,flannel,crossed arms` Also it finds more results then before (results that shouldn't be there). And if you look at the last code block in my first post, something like that is very welcome.
Thanks so far.

Comment: I fix the query, leave also the "broken" one for your comment.

Comment: `Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in ( select se.id from nv_entries se JOIN nv_tags st on st.entrie_id = se.id ' at line 5` I tried to change line 5 to `select e.id` but that didn't help. Also is the double `in` at line 4 correct? If i remove one then i have no error but no result either...

Comment: there were a "in in" instead of "in". Fixed.